# Stripe STPCustomerDeserializer unable to parse customer Swift

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

Customer JSON returned from Stripe API unable to be parsed by using                                 STPCustomerDeserializer(jsonResponse: data), returns nil when locating the "id" field. logging the data shows that the id is not nil.

The customer object is in the exact same format as what the Stripe API returns. Error message 'The response from Stripe failed to get parsed into valid JSON."

Debugging the deserialiser shows that it is failing here:

```
// required fields
NSString *stripeId = [dict stp_stringForKey:@"id"];
if (!stripeId) {
    return nil; <<< returning here
}
```

at >>>

```
- (nullable NSString *)stp_stringForKey:(NSString *)key {
    id value = self[key];
    if (value && [value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        return value;
    }
    return nil; << returning here
}
```

I have tried passing in the customer data in different formats to no avail.

I saw someone asks a similar question here [The data could not be read because it isn't in the correct format JSON & SWIFT 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494186/the-data-could-not-be-read-because-it-isnt-in-the-correct-format-json-swift-3)

```
["customer": {
    "account_balance" = 0;
    address = "<null>";
    balance = 0;
    created = ***;
    currency = "<null>";
    "default_source" = “***”;
    delinquent = 0;
    description = "<null>";
    discount = "<null>";
    email = “***”;
    id = "cus_***";
    "invoice_prefix" = ***;
    "invoice_settings" =     {
        "custom_fields" = "<null>";
        "default_payment_method" = "<null>";
        footer = "<null>";
    };
    livemode = 1;
    metadata =     {
    };
    name = "<null>";
    object = customer;
    phone = "<null>";
    "preferred_locales" =     (
    );
    shipping = "<null>";
    sources =     {
        data =         (
                        {
                "address_city" = "<null>";
                "address_country" = GB;
                "address_line1" = "<null>";
                "address_line1_check" = "<null>";
                "address_line2" = "<null>";
                "address_state" = "<null>";
                "address_zip" = "<null>";
                "address_zip_check" = "<null>";
                brand = Visa;
                country = GB;
                customer = "cus_***";
                "cvc_check" = pass;
                "dynamic_last4" = "<null>";
                "exp_month" = ***;
                "exp_year" = ***;
                fingerprint = ***;
                funding = debit;
                id = "card_***";
                last4 = ***;
                metadata =                 {
                };
                name = "<null>";
                object = card;
                "tokenization_method" = "<null>";
            }
        );
        "has_more" = 0;
        object = list;
        "total_count" = 1;
        url = "/v1/customers/cus_***/sources";
    };
    subscriptions =     {
        data =         (
        );
        "has_more" = 0;
        object = list;
        "total_count" = 0;
        url = "/v1/customers/cus_***/subscriptions";
    };
    "tax_exempt" = none;
    "tax_ids" =     {
        data =         (
        );
        "has_more" = 0;
        object = list;
        "total_count" = 0;
        url = "/v1/customers/cus_***/tax_ids";
    };
    "tax_info" = "<null>";
    "tax_info_verification" = "<null>";
}]
```

Comment: share the JSON example please

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a similar issue, error in this case seems to be that a key is not found. Try making the variables in your model optionals (?).If it doesn't have a value it will return nil or the value associated.

Are you sure the id which you mentioned is NSString, try with NSInteger or other DataTypes.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I just needed to subscript into the json using `data["customer"]` as `Any`.